# Como evaluar si un audio se esta reproduciendo

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Buenas estoy haciendo un reproductor de audio con *angular js*. Pude lograr que el botón reciba la *URL* del audio y ejecutar ese audio mediante una función, pero estoy teniendo problemas para hacer que ese audio se pause cuando presione el botón y se reanude desde el punto donde lo deje.

```js
var app = angular.module('audioApp',[])

app.controller('audioController',function($scope){
    // texto botón reproducir
    $scope.playText = "Reproducir";

    // imagen botón reproducir
    $scope.pauseBtn = 'img/ic_reproductor_play_normal.png';

    // función para cambiar la imagen y el texto del boton
    $scope.changeImg = function() {
        if($scope.playText == 'Reproducir') {

            // sí el playText dice "Reproducir" cambiamos a "Pausar"
            $scope.playText = "Pausar";
            $scope.pauseBtn = 'img/ic_reproductor_pausa_normal.png';


            playAudio();

        } else if($scope.playText == 'Pausar') {

            // sí el playText dice "Pausar" cambiamos a "Reproducir"
            $scope.playText = "Reproducir";
            $scope.pauseBtn = 'img/ic_reproductor_play_normal.png';



        }
    }


    //Función para reproducir un audio

    function playAudio(){

        var req = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACc86242677f1f69823986da845f65eb27/Messages/MMa5d0dc372fd919c57048757f49ddb383/Media/ME8f416923ff48c0d2ab850602b8d165b4';

        var audio = new Audio(req);

        audio.play();


    }


    })
```

```css
.receptor{
    font: 110% Roboto;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
}


.boton_reproducir{
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font: 90% Roboto;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.div-boton-reproducir{
    width: 9rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="audioApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.32/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="audioController">
        <div class="div-boton-reproducir">
            <div class="receptor">
                <button class="boton_reproducir" ng-click="changeImg()">
                    <img ng-src="{{pauseBtn}}"/>
                    <b>{{playText}}</b>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que te valga esta respuesta. He tratado de comentar en el código la mayoría de cosas y detalles, así que espero que queden todos los cambios más o menos claros.

Los puntos importanes y documentación:

- [El elemento AUDIO DE HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_src.asp) Importante que lo revises.
- He separado la función de carga del audio para que sea independiente del play. Uno de los problemas era que lo recargabas continuamente al dar a play, pues volvías a crear el objeto.
- He aislado la función de cambiar texto de los botones y la de play o pause. De este modo, la capa de presentación y lógica están algo más separadas. Te he dejado notas al respecto en el código.
- He añadido iconos que se veían, y los he controlado con un ng-íf (en el código encontrarás enlaces a la documentación), mucho más cómodo si utilizas angularjs que hacerlo en modo "Jquery" que era un poco lo que hacías.
- llamo al método pause o play del Audio en función de las propiedades del objeto audio. De este modo no tengo que crear if extraños, ni controles, si no que accedo a sus propiedades y sé si se está reproduciendo o no.

Creo que no me dejo nada.  Si ves que pueda faltar algo coméntame!!

Un saludo

```js
var app = angular.module('audioApp', [])

app.controller('audioController', function($scope) {
  // texto botón reproducir
  $scope.playText = "Reproducir";
  //AÑADO AQUÍ EL AUDIO PARA QUE SEA ACCESIBLE POR TODAS LAS FUNCIONES


  var req = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACc86242677f1f69823986da845f65eb27/Messages/MMa5d0dc372fd919c57048757f49ddb383/Media/ME8f416923ff48c0d2ab850602b8d165b4';


  //Inicio un audio para todo el controller

  $scope.audio = new Audio();

  //Este audio puedes cargarlo después con un parámetro cuando quieras
  loadAudio(req);

  // imagen botón reproducir
  $scope.pauseBtn = 'img/ic_reproductor_play_normal.png';

  // función para cambiar la imagen y el texto del boton
  // Como verás, lo que he hecho es separar la función de changeImg y quitarle la llamada a la reproducción. Es un error asignar esa funcionalidad dentro del cambio de imagen, ya que estás ligando la funcionalidad a la presentación, y debería ser al contrario. Yo he creado una función "playAudio" que cuando se ejecuta, llama a la función changeImg, siendo esta la encargada de decidir si debe pintar una u otra cosa. 

  $scope.changeImg = function() {
    //Puedes acceder a las propiedades del objeto audio estándares https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_src.asp para saber si está pausado o no

    if (!$scope.audio.paused) {
      //Sí el playText dice "Reproducir" cambiamos a "Pausar"
      $scope.playText = "Pausar";

    } else if ($scope.audio.paused) {
      // sí el playText dice "Pausar" cambiamos a "Reproducir"
      $scope.playText = "Reproducir";
    }
  }


  //Esta función podrías llamarla después de obtener cualquier url a tu gusto. Únicamente asocia esa URL al audio

  function loadAudio(reqUrl) {
    $scope.audio.src = reqUrl;
  }

  //Función para reproducir un audio. 
  //En este caso, si observas, llamo a los métodos pause o play en función de las variables propias del objeto de HTML Audio.
  $scope.playAudio = function() {
    if ($scope.audio.paused) {
      $scope.audio.play();
    } else {
      $scope.audio.pause();
    }
    //Además, llamo al método de cambiar la imagen.
    $scope.changeImg();
  }




})
```

```css
.receptor {
  font: 110% Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

.boton_reproducir {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font: 90% Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-boton-reproducir {
  width: 9rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="audioApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Audio Angular</title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Espero que el ejemplo te valga. Creo que es completamente funcional.</h3>
  <p><i>Verás que he añadido también el botón pause o play como <a href="https://icons.getbootstrap.com" target="_blank">iconos</a>, y con <a href="https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf" target="_blank">ng-if</a> controlo fácilmente que aparezca uno u otro</i></p>

  <div ng-controller="audioController">
    <div class="div-boton-reproducir">
      <div class="receptor">
        <button class="boton_reproducir" ng-click="playAudio()">
                    
                    <b>{{playText}}</b>
                    <svg ng-if="!audio.paused"  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-pause-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M5.5 3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 5v6a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-3 0V5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5-1.5zm5 0A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 12 5v6a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-3 0V5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5-1.5z"/>
</svg>
<svg ng-if="audio.paused" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-play-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M11.596 8.697l-6.363 3.692c-.54.313-1.233-.066-1.233-.697V4.308c0-.63.692-1.01 1.233-.696l6.363 3.692a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.393z"/>
</svg>
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```